# Why did my embedded website refuse to connect?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I'm unsure as to why my embedded websites are all refusing to connect when I load a webpage I get this error "www.exaplesite.com refused to connect." if anyone could help me to fix this error it would be much appreciated.

My Code:

```
            <div id="Container"
                style="padding-bottom:56.25%; position:relative; display:block; width: 100%;">
                <iframe id="ViostreamIframe" width="100%" height="1000px" src="https://www.example.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="position:absolute; left: 0; margin-top: 3.4%"></iframe>
            </div>
```

Comment: Or you forgot to write a proper question or it is some kind of joke. Anyway please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix this from Power Apps Portal side. Most probably web site that you try to embed as an iframe doesn't allow to be embedded. You need to update X-Frame-Options on the website that you are trying to embed to allow your Power Apps Portal (if you have control over that website). You can find more [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)